# How to add Multiple Texts over image in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

**Hello guys**

I'm making a simple image editor in react native. In which I'm adding multiple text over a image. But as soon as I added one more text over image, the all text comes to an initial position, but I want to place them as where they were before.

***Like in PicsArt***

**where we can add multiple text over image and all the text have their position where they moved or dragged and resized. When the new text is added, previous text have their previous position.**

**How to do that?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Some code that you've already written would help and perhaps the visual representation of the position of the text would help in understanding what you're trying to achieve. Generally, if you want to keep adding new text and the new text should be positioned where the previous text was, I would map over an array of text messages to display it over the image.

Comment: All the text should have their previous position where they moved before? A newly added text should be at initial position but the previous text have to be where they were before.